# how do I get additional scopes using SocialAuth.NET for FaceBook?

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, parameters

Heres what I am trying to achieve, basically I want to retrieve the users details and an additional parameter by adding an additional parameter(user_location).

I have put this in the web.config(xx replacing my keys):

```
                        var profile = UserProfileBLL.RetrieveProfileByUserID(Guid.Parse(user.ProviderUserKey.ToString()));
                        profile.facebookSynced = true;
                        profile.validEmail = true;
                        profile.Country = country;

                       var test = new Brickred.SocialAuth.NET.Core.Wrappers.FacebookWrapper();
                       string city = test.AdditionalScopes[0].ToString();
```

I am not sure if this right at all and I cant seem to find out exactly how to use this and I've done a lot of googling to no avail.  The documentation is limited to say to least.  I am not sure if by the time I request this parameter that the user has already been authenticated etc.

Its probably incorrect hence why I need a bit of guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Curious, Why do you need to retrieve Scope? Once you add additional_scopes, SocialAuth.NET automatically passes them onto Facebook when user's redirected for login.